# Fill textarea using spynner

Tags: textarea, spynner

Is it possible to fill the textarea using spynner? How can I do it?
I try this:

```
sb.fill("textarea[name=NAME]","TEXT")
```

But it doesn't work.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution, I'm using the webkit fill:

```
wk_fill("textarea[name=NAME]","TEXT")
```